# Subfolders in static Azure hostings

Tags: html, azure, static, azure-storage

I want to use an Azure blob file storage to host a static website.

This works fine, if the html-page is located in the root folder of the $web-storage.

But if I put the webpage into a subfolder, the relative links (e.g. to css files) don't work anymore - since they are interpreted as root-based links

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

index.html is located in "subfolder1"

But instead of

```
https://blablabla.web.core.windows.net/subfolder1/css
```

it is resolved to

```
https://blablabla.web.core.windows.net/css
```

Is this an error of Azure or a misunderstanding/error in my html?

Comment: Is index.html your root document?

Comment: index.html is located in /subfolder1/ ... if I put it directly under root "/" everything works, since then /css exists ... but putting all under /subfolder1/index.html and subfolder1/css it fails

Comment: I guess the question I am asking is how are you accessing index.html? Is it like `https://blablabla.web.core.windows.net` or `https://blablabla.web.core.windows.net/subfolder1/index.html`?

Comment: The last one: https://blablabla.web.core.windows.net/subfolder1/index.html

Answer (score 5):

Actually, `$web` is a special container on Azure General Purpose Storage V2, which be the root path like `www` for Apache HTTP server or `wwwroot` for IIS to hosts all static folders and files. All folders and their subfolders must have to be created in `$web` container. You can see its information on Azure portal as the figure below.

[image]

Here is my sample to create two folders `a` & `b` and their `index.html` under `$web` container in Azure Storage Explorer.

[image]

If access my primary endpoint `https://<account name>.z7.web.core.windows.net`, the index web page of my static website is an Angular sample web page as below,

[image]

Then, to access the subfolder `a` and `b` like you want, the index page of these subfolders as below.

## index.html of folder `a`

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>A</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]

Hope it helps for understanding the structure of static website on Azure General Purpose Storage V2.

---

**Update for your comment:**

I update my `a/index.html` file and add a new file `a/a.css`, the codes as below.

## a/index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="a.css">
</head>
<body>
<h2>A</h2>
<span id='test'>Hello</span>
</body>
</html>
```

## a/a.css

```
#test {
    color: red;
}
```

There are some behavior up to the browser implement.

Q: What's the difference between `http://host/a` and `http://host/a/`? 
A: To access them in Chrome, the two urls will response the same content from `a/index.html`. However, their base paths are different: `/` for `http://host/a` , but `/a/` for `http://host/a/`, that will cause different behavor for loading a relative path resource of `a.css`, as the figures below.

Fig 1.

[image]

Fig 2.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Peter ... The problem lies one step further: If you include in your index.html in folder "a" a css or js with href="my.css" it is not searched for in the same folder ("a") the index.html is located, but in the root /my.css

Comment: Thank you for your effort! Is that a special behavior of azure or a normal one on common webservers like apache and iis? the problem: The user never will add the additional "/" at the end of the url.

Comment: Hi @PeterPan thanks for the tip about the URL. Isn't that possible to bypass this behavior ? And to be sure that the `a/index.html` uses the good base URL ?

Comment: @Konrad The behavior described is a standard web behavior: if the HTML URL is `/name`, and the HTML loads a resource with relative path `othername`, then the browser will look for `/othername` - because both look like files in `/`. What you'd expect - and how other servers are doing this - is when you access `/name`, the server knows its a "folder" and redirects the browser automatically to `/name/` and only when the request ends with a `/` does the index gets loaded. Then when a relative `othername` ref occurs, the browser understands it as `/name/othername`. Azure apparently doesn't do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can setup a [base tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) to get absolute URLs to work. So, adding this to under `html > head` should do the trick

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="/subfolder1/" />
    ...
  </head>
  ...
</html>
```