# Static hosting - multiple websites in a single blob storage account

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-deployment-slots

I want to be able to host multiple versions of the website in a single $web container and use some routing method to specify the default folder.

I have tried creating 2 folders (WEB1 and WEB2) inside the $web container and uploaded a different version of the website into each (production version into WEB1 and staging version into WEB2). Then I explicitly access the folder in the URL (like STATIC-WEB-URL/WEB1) and get to see my website.

The problem is that as soon as I access the STATIC-WEB-URL/WEB1
the website is downloaded (which is great) but the URL immediately changes to STATIC-WEB-URL/#

This is a problem as if I refresh the page again, it results in 404.

Just for some context: I am trying to mimic the deployment slot option in app service. To be able to have a staging and a production slot.

Comment: The answer here explains it very well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56703196/subfolders-in-static-azure-hostings

Answer (score 4):

You need to update the base url in index.html page
changes -> base href="/web1/"