# Hosting Multiple Static Web Apps on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-static-web-app

I have multiple static web apps (5 to 6) that I need to host on Azure. I will be accessing the Web Apps like example.com/app1, example.com/app2 and so on; where each app after the slash is completely separate static web app. Given this requirements I have few questions

- Can I host all the static Web apps in same storage account ? or do I need to create storage account for each static web app ?
- Do I need Single Azure CDN for all those static web apps or should I be using CDN for each storage account separately ? I am aware we can use rules to redirect to right static web apps but creating one to one mapping of CDN with static web apps would have any cost implications ?

What could be the preferred way given the above requirements ?

Thanks

Comment: instead of folders would you be open to use subdomains? You would have to use different storage accounts. The issue when using an Azure CDN you assign the custom domain on the Endpoint. The endpoint would also connect to the various storage account. So you would be unable to have the same domain across multiple endpoints.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @ron . Azure CDN can point to multiple storage accounts (multiple origions) and request can be controlled via custom rules (pointing to respected origion based on URL). However I am not sure if that's a good idea and would there be any cost implications or anything else that I am missing.

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56703196/subfolders-in-static-azure-hostings

Comment: @ImranArshad you are correct. Storage accounts you should only be charged for storage used, so separating them out would make sense. The other issue again is when you assign a domain typically happens at the endpoint with connects with  the endpoint that connects to the custom domain.

Answer (score 0):

According to one MSFT's [answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/254127/hosting-multiple-static-websites-on-azure-blob-sto.html):
actually it's **not** possible to host multiple static website in **one** storage account. You should create a **separate Azure Storage Account for each static website**.

Although multiple static apps is not achievable, sub folder is achievable, which would also meet your need. You could check the link I post as a comment: [Subfolders in static Azure hostings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56703196/subfolders-in-static-azure-hostings)